# CSS Dropdown Menu missing Background

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, background-color

My Dropdown-Menu Background only appears when hovering over the Dropdown sites, but I want it to appear all the time.

My Site is: http://bellezza-ribelle.blogspot.de/ 
There are Dropdowns on "Meine Bücher", "Rezensionen" and "Challenges" but the background only shows on the first Dropdown-Tabs, which makes it difficult the read the other ones, if you don't hover over them.

How can I make the Background appear on the drop-down-tabs with only hovering over die "Main"-Tabs (Meine Bücher, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add this to your CSS:

```
#nav1 ul ul li {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

You can also have more "air" by using padding for the li:

[image]

```
#nav1 ul ul li {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a little issue with your `max-height` @ `.tabs-inner .widget ul` on `Line 255`. Maybe setup a different `max-height` on `:hover`?